# Date Field Operator in "where" parameter of @wire LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, wire, where

**Introduction**

I am trying to use the "where" parameter provided by the "getRelatedListRecords" of "uiRelatedListApi" within @wire in LWC (reference 1).

Specifically, I am having trouble when trying to use a date operator in its "where" parameter.

The official documentation of "getRelatedListRecords" provides the "where" cause as a parameter (reference 1), as shown here:

> where—(Optional) The filter to apply to related list records, in GraphQL syntax.

**Problem**

I would like to use the "where" parameter in @wire in a way it would be equivalent to this SOQL, considering the `Visit_Hour__c` field is of type Datetime:

```
SELECT Id FROM My_Child_Object__c WHERE DAY_ONLY(Visit_Hour__c) = 2024-01-03
```

When I execute this SOQL in my org it works perfectly. The problem is how the `DATE_ONLY` operator is used in the "where" parameter of the @wire method...

Salesforce's Official documentation provides an example of how to use field operators in @wire's "where" parameter, as shown in this example (reference 2):

> ```
> where: { CreatedDate : { CALENDAR_YEAR: { value: { eq: 2022 } } } }
> ```

Aplying the logic provided in the example, my code was looking like this:

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'My_Child_Objects__r',
        fields: FIELDS_LIST,
        where: '{ Visit_Hour__c: { DATE_ONLY: { value: { eq: 2024-01-03 } } } }'
    })
    relatedRecords({ error, data }) {
        if( data ) {
           // my logic goes here
        } 
        else if( error ) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

Nonetheles, this code gives this error: `Invalid Date value: {"eq":"2024-01-03"}.`

**Wrap up**

Problem is: even when I used the same example provided by Salesforce, an error persists and I can't use the date field operator. The "where" parameter used in @wire and error are as follows:

```
where: '{ CreatedDate : { CALENDAR_YEAR: { value: { eq: 2024 } } } }'
Invalid Date value: {"eq":2024}.
```

Based on what I've tested, it just seems like using the date field operator does not work at all with @wire...

Has anyone ever tried using this and knows where I may have failed to make it to work?

---

**References**

1. Official documentation for "getRelatedListRecords" and example:
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-get-related-list-records.html#parameters
2. Official query examples with date field operators: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/filter-fields.html#example-queries

Answer (score 0):

The error may arise due to Apex interpreting the date as a string when passed as an argument to an Apex function. To address this, utilize the following Apex code for converting a date string into an instance of the standard Date class. Ensure the date string adheres to the YYYY-MM-DD format.

**`Date x = Date.valueOf('2024-01-03');`**

where: '{ Visit_Hour__c: { DATE_ONLY: { value: { eq: ' + Date.valueOf('2024-01-03') + ' } } } }'